# How to Login to my app using Google credentials without redirection in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-api, google-oauth

I am currently working on a project that requires a user to Login to the app using Google credentials but without redirection to the google authentication website. The user needs to enter his Gmail id and password in the app window and somehow I need to verify these credentials with Google (without redirecting). Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT:**
One approach I got is to send these credentials to google which would authenticate the credentials and return an authentication token. But the feasibility of this approach is questionable.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It sounds like you want something like IdentityServer (http://identityserver.io/), but it's difficult to say without knowing more detail and what you've already tried

Comment: I have tried with Google Oauth2 but it redirects to the google SignIn page when I click on "SignIn through Google link", which I am trying to avoid. Thanks @Brandon